# Laptop keyboard typing + on its own

Tags: drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using an HP Laptop with intel core i5 (8th Generation) and 8GB RAM. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Recently I am facing a strange issue. Whenever I am trying to type something, my keyboard is typing '+' signs on its own. And it's kind of unstoppable. I have to repeatedly press the backspace in order to delete them but it keeps on typing. It is highly frustrating. I am unsure whether it is due to a stuck key or a faulty driver. I tried with an USB keyboard but could not understand properly, because both the embedded keyboard and external keyboard are active and therefore, it kept on typing '+' as usual.

Is there any way to stop this issue? How can I change keyboard driver or at least understand what is causing this problem? And also, is there anything like keytweak which I can use on ubuntu?

Comment: I do not think its the driver, you probably guessed correctly when you said stuck key.

Comment: I would personally boot a *live* system that is different to your installed OS (ie. not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system) so you're using a very different software stack & none of your configuration files, and see if it occurs there. If it occurs on that *live* system, then it's likely your hardware (and a really stuck key).  I'd likely use `xev` to explore the issue, but from *live* media & not your installed OS.  *By non-20.04 LTS, you weren't specific as to what system, likely desktop so likely using HWE kernel, so I'd also avoid 20.10 there too..  even maybe Debian or whatever I had around*